# php exec an echo with variables and string

Tags: php

I want to to exchange "30" and "16" with two variables "hour" and "mins" in a php exec function

```
$hour = 30;
$mins = 16;
exec('echo "30 16 * * * sudo /home/pi/raspberry-remote/./send 11010 1 1" | crontab -');
```

and changed it like that:

```
exec('echo "$hour $mins * * * sudo /home/pi/raspberry-remote/./send 11010 1 1" | crontab -');
```

How can i get this right? Thank you

Comment: Just concatenate it like: `'echo "' . $hour . ' ' . $mins . '`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables inside single quoted strings are not populated. Try either

```
exec('echo "'.$hour.' '.$mins.' * * * sudo /home/pi/raspberry-remote/./send 11010 1 1" | crontab -');
```

or

```
exec("echo \"$hour $mins * * * sudo /home/pi/raspberry-remote/./send 11010 1 1\" | crontab -");
```

[PHP String Documentation](http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Answer (score 2):

Variables aren't expanded inside single-quoted strings, only inside double-quoted strings. So switch your quotes around.

```
exec("echo '$hour $mins * * * sudo /home/pi/raspberry-remote/./send 11010 1 1' | crontab -");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using concat string

```
exec('echo "'.$hour.' ' .$mins.' * * * sudo /home/pi/raspberry-remote/./send 11010 1 1" | crontab -');exec('echo "$hour $mins * * * sudo /home/pi/raspberry-remote/./send 11010 1 1" | crontab -');
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you **[sprintf](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)**. That does not lose readability.

```
$format = 'echo "%d %d * * * sudo /home/pi/raspberry-remote/./send 11010 1 1" | crontab -';
exec(sprintf($format, $hour, $mins));
```